# How to edit this code to only paste the value using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code in VBA to copy and paste into the next empty cell in column DK, but given that the original cell is a function, the pasted value shows up as 0. Is there any way to paste only the value of the original cell?

```
Sub CopyToDK()
Range("CN59").Copy Range("DK" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)                                               
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to copy the value, you can do this...

```
Sub CopyToDK()
Range("DK" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp) = Range("CN59")                                               
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Range("CN59").Copy
Range("DK" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```